# Error sending audio.wav file from React to Django

Tags: python, reactjs, django, audio

I'm working on building a transcription app using React and Django. I'm trying to figure out how to play the audio that is uploaded to my server. I'm able to record and send the audio on React using `react-media-recorder` but once it gets to backend, I get an error in VS code that reads 'An error occurred while laoding the audio file.' It's weird. The error is not appearing in my server dialogue. At first I thought it was my views.py file, but I'm starting to think it's a different problem. Here is my views file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from . models import *
from . serializer import *
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import JsonResponse
# Create your views here.

class AudioUploadView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        output = [{"upload": output.file}
                  for output in Audio.objects.all()]
        return Response(output)

    def post(self, request):
        print('hello', request.data.get('audio'))
        audio_blob = request.data.get('audio')
    # save file to path
        with open('audio.wav', 'wb') as audio_file:
                for chunk in audio_blob.chunks():
                    audio_file.write(chunk)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'New audio uploaded'})# convert audio to .wav file
```

The output is 'hello, audio.wav'

Here is my model file. I realize this could possibly be a problem with how my models are working, too.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Audio(models.Model):
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/%Y/%m/%d/')
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.audio_file.name
```

I checked the permissions on the audio file. I'm getting 'audio.wav -- rw-r-r' which I believe means I have read and write permissions. So that's good, right?

I added this to the settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I also checked and wav files should handle fine on Django.

The file path appears to be ok because I'm getting the audio.wav file to appear in my django directory.

I've tried playing this file in finder through iTunes and other media players and it's not working. Does this mean the file is corrupted? It plays ok on the frontend but then seems to break when I upload to backend.
Not sure if this is fixable. Thanks for any suggestions.